# Odoo 17 error: @spreadsheet/hooks: The following modules are needed by other modules but have not been defined

Tags: javascript, odoo, qweb, odoo-17

I have an Odoo 17 on-premise install. I installed some modules and then somehow this error started showing in the browser directly when clicking on the dashboard app:

```
The following modules are needed by other modules but have not been defined, they may not be present in the correct asset bundle:

    @spreadsheet/hooks

The following modules could not be loaded because they have unmet dependencies, this is a secondary error which is likely caused by one of the above problems:

    @spreadsheet_edition/bundle/actions/abstract_spreadsheet_action
    @spreadsheet_dashboard_edition/bundle/action/dashboard_edit_action
```

I couldn't find anything in GitHub issues or other places regarding this error. How could something like this happen, and how can I repair it, without needing to start a new database from scratch? Can I somehow find the code that is missing and install it once again?

There seems to be some JS code missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is JavaScript code missing.  You are on an on-premise database, so I would assume that your core Odoo source code might be behind the enterprise source code.  The enterprise code references spreadsheet imports in the community code.  Try making sure both sources are up to date, restart the database, and it should solve the issue.  You do not need to re-create the database from scratch.

Comment: Hi @automatejake. I indeed thought first that there was a problem between enterprise modules and our odoo install. However, after many attempts of bringing everything together, the problem was found to be in the bitnami odoo docker image we were using. We switched to the official docker image and have had no problem since then.

Comment: The official docker image is updated regularly and contains the latest sources for the Odoo community code.  The problem was almost definitely because of a mismatch in the enterprise and community code.  Glad that you were able to resolve the issue!